# MAM: Is the bundle, used to create masked payload signature, not normalized?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

I am researching how Masked Authenticated Messaging (MAM) works. The masked_payload is created in the create function in file: https://github.com/iotaledger/MAM/blob/master/mam/src/mam.rs

masked_payload = [ Encoded Index, Encoded Message Length, encrypted [ Message, Nonce, Signature, Encoded Number of Siblings, Siblings ] ]

My question is: The signature in the masked payload is created based on the bundle. The bundle does not seem to be normalized, meaning tryte value M is allowed in the bundle. Is my assumption correct?